# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in webpack 5/Angular 14

Tags: angular, angular14

While running a project with [deepstream.io-client-js][1] installed in angular 14, getting following error.
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepstream.io-client-js

````
BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
        - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "url": false }```
````

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As we can see in error there are 2 steps to add polyfill, first create a ***webpack.config.js*** file at ***tsconfig.json*** level and add the code as below.

Step 1.
***webpack.config.js***

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }
  }
};
```

step 2. run npm i url for ***- install 'url'***

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at your import statements. Make sure you are using:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
```

instead of `router` from `express` package.

Comment: This is nothing to do with typescript code, it is npm dependency issue, I have added this question and answered by myself so that anyone find the issue, will able to solve it easily.

Comment: tnx, this solve my problem

Comment: @PrashantSingh You might want to mark your answer as the accepted answer.

Comment: @KitPeters Sorry didn't get you?

Comment: @PrashantSingh Looks like you figured it out :)

Comment: Thanks. This was the exact problem I had. Its resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

Refering to the original error message, it's also possible to use a webpack plugin to automatically use polyfill when possible :

add package to your project by running :

```
npm install node-polyfill-webpack-plugin
```

add the plugin to webpack.config.js file :

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")
```

then, in same file, add the plugin to you config :

```
plugins: [
  new NodePolyfillPlugin()
]
```

https://github.com/Richienb/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin

The plugin does what Prashant does plus many more others similar. It could be usefull on large project with a lot of unresolved dependency.